# parallel testing with selenium + nose

Tags: python, selenium, multiprocessing, nosetests, parallel-testing

I am trying to run the functional tests in parallel with multiprocess plugin which gives me random TimeoutException sometimes

my tests are really simple, each of them just goes to a webpage and check if certain element exists.

does anybody know what might be the cause?

thanks

Comment: The cause is your webpage is timing out.  But really, there isn't any way to answer this question-- you need to provide further details.

Comment: it's actually not the webpage timeout, but a TimedOutException raised by the multiprocess plugin:

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/nose/plugins/multiprocess.py", line 261, in signalhandler
    raise TimedOutException()

Answer (score 7):

Try running nosetests with the --process-timeout value set to something higher than your tests would reasonably take:

nosetests --processes=2 --process-timeout=120